# gitbash Permission to xxx//python.git denied to xxx

Tags: git, github, git-bash

One year ago, I used gitbash and set my global username and user email, now I changed them and after trying to push my files to github, it gives me this error: Permission to xxx//python.git denied to xxx. But when I check current username with git config global --list, the username is not xxx.

I also tried to look environment variables, but couldn't see that "xxx" username, maybe I am lookin in the wrong place.

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` have NOTHING AT ALL to do with authentication (they are for authorship and nothing else). What's the output of `git remote -v` in that repo?

Comment: the output is the github repository i am trying to push now.

Comment: Are you going to give any details?